# mysql_query returns nulls

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a php script which queries mysql for a certain row based on it's id.

This works fine for the first 3 rows , but on the 4th it returns nulls on all fields.

Here's the query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT ind,title,body,img,tags,live FROM project WHERE ind = '".$curid."' ")
```

let me know if you need to see more code.

Comment: Probably because `ind` is never that value of `$curid`. Print out the values of `$curid` to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that the forth row doesn't have the id you think it does. Return them all (remove the where statement) and output them to the screen to check, or use a database browsing tool, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Try some debugging..

```
$q = "SELECT ind,title,body,img,tags,live FROM project WHERE ind = '".$curid."' ";
$rs = mysql_query($q) or die("MySQL error in Query: ". $q ."<br><br>The error is:<br>".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

when you execute query, change **$curid** by value that you consider is correct. verify result, if yet get null values, you can do it:

```
mysql_query("SELECT ind,title,body,img,tags,live FROM project WHERE ind = '".$curid."' " and
ind  IS NOT NULL and title IS NOT NULL 
)
```

for example